# $S'_n=S_{2n}-S_n/4 , \forall n\in N$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Let $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n 1/k^2$ and $S'_n=\sum_{k=1}^n 1/(2k-1)^2$ be partial sums.
>   Verify that $S'_n=S_{2n}-S_n/4 , \forall n\in N$.

As it is real-analysis, it is not allowed to use calculus, only basic math.
One of my tries was to separate 
$$S_{2n}=\sum_{k=1}^n1/k^2+\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}1/k^2$$ 
and then multiply and divide it by four, so that I can delete the other part of the condition so I can arrange the equation so it is easier to prove. Still not make any significant progress in this particular problem.
Any suggestions?

Comment: How do I do to highlight the important part of the description?

Answer (score 1):

Splitting into even and odd terms we get $S_{2n}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2n}\frac 1 {k^{2}}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac 1 {(2k)^{2}}+\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac 1 {((2k-1)^{2}}$ Now just write $(2k)^{2}$ as $4 {k^{2}}$ in the first term. This gives $S_{2n}=\frac 1 4 S_n+S_n'$.